# Only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]

Tags: angular

This is my configuration in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
"angular2-universal": "^0.104.5",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^1.0.2",
"css": "^2.2.1",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
"isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
"preboot": "^2.0.10",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12"
}
```

And this is my code:

```
bootstrap(App, [
...HTTP_PROVIDERS,
FormBuilder,
AuthGuard,
AuthenticationService,
provideRouter(routes)
]);
```

And I get the error "Only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]". WHat does that mean? Where is my error?

The error seems to be in provideRouter(routes) part.

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'counter', component: Counter },
{ path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchData },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

This is the definition of the routes.

Comment: What is `fakeBackendProvider`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Please check the updated code, the error happens without fakeBackendProvider so I deleted it.

Comment: Did you import everything properly? There is no need to use `...` for `HTTP_PROVIDERS` (just a hint, not related to the error).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, I checked. You can see the updated question again, added some details.

Comment: The error message means that one of the providers is just an object. A provider has to be a type or an object like `{provider: TypeOrToken, useXxx: TypeOrValueOrFunction }` and one of your provider doesn't seem to match one of these supported kinds. Usually this is because something provided just can't be a provider or an import is broken and therefore the provided token is not what you expect to be.